# xcode 4.6.2 instruments doesn't work on device

Tags: xcode, instruments

I am running Xcode 4.6.2 and trying to run Instruments (4.6) on a device (a 4th generation iPod).  Compiling and running on the device is no problem whatever.  Neither is profiling on the simulator.  When I try to profile on the device itself compilation and installation seem to occur normally but after Instruments launches an error sound is heard, the app never starts on the device, no output is visible in Xcode, no recording seems to take place in Instruments and the red circle 'record' button stays grayed-out.

The only feedback I see is "Finished running - Profiling xxxx.app" in the 'status window' of the 'toolbar' at the top of my Xcode window.

EDIT: More info.  After doing more research I have discovered that there is info on the device log pertaining to this issue.

When I try to run instruments I get:

SpringBoard[17] : Killing com.abc.appname for termination assertion

installd[13786] : entitlement 'keychain-access-groups' has value not permitted by a provisioning profile

installd[13786] : entitlement 'aps-environment' has value not permitted by a provisioning profile

installd[13786] : entitlement 'application-identifier' has value not permitted by a provisioning profile

installd[13786] : entitlement 'keychain-access-groups' has value not permitted by a provisioning profile

installd[13786] : entitlement 'aps-environment' has value not permitted by a provisioning profile

installd[13786] : entitlement 'application-identifier' has value not permitted by a provisioning profile

Suggestions from various other similar posts have been tried and have failed:

- Un-installing app from device and re-installing - fails the same
- Adding provisioning profile info to 'entitlements.plist' or, variously, 'entitlements.entitlements', or 'appname.entitlements' - fails the same
- Manually changing the 'scheme' via 'Product' -> 'Scheme' -> 'Edit Scheme...' Profiling scheme from using the release build configuration to the debug configuration - fails the same
- Manually deleting all provisioning profiles in xcode, clearing all code signing identities in the project and the target, saving them, restarting Xcode, reimporting provisioning profiles and re-assigning the code signing identitites. - fails